# Transferring a string to new activity + convert string to integer

Tags: android, string, button, android-activity

First off, i'll post a picture to make it easier for you guys to understand.

[image]

As you can see, there's an EditText and a button.
I want the button to save the contents of the EditText into a string + start a new activity.

In the next activity, i then want to convert the string into an Integer.

This is my current code:

**SENDER ACTIVITY**

```
        startscore = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.startscore);

proceed = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bProceed);
proceed.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Introscreen.this, BillardScoreboardActivity.class);
        String s = startscore.getText().toString();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("lol", s);
        //put into your intent
        myIntent.putExtras(b);
        Introscreen.this.startActivity(myIntent);

    }
}); 
}
```

**RECEIVER ACTIVITY**

```
        int counter1, counter2, counter3, counter4, counter5;

            oncreate.....{

            Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String s = b.getString("lol");




    column1tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.column1text);
    column2tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.column2text);
    column3tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.column3text);
    column4tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.column4text);
    column5tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.column5text);

    column1tv.setText(counter1);
    column2tv.setText(counter2);
    column3tv.setText(counter3);
    column4tv.setText(counter4);
    column5tv.setText(counter5);
```

Hope you can help me troubleshooting it, to figure out the problem.

**The problem:**

Upon clicking the button, it shuts down the application and gives me those error codes:

```
02-23 15:01:24.136: E/AndroidRuntime(295): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{inno.games/inno.games.BillardScoreboardActivity}:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)

at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer

at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:412)

at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:382)

at inno.games.BillardScoreboardActivity.onCreate(BillardScoreboardActivity.java:35)

at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)

... 11 more
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's breaking while trying to convert an empty string to an integer. Something is wrong while passing your string to the next activity. Try passing your string extra through a bundle instead:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("key", string);
//put into your intent
yourIntent.putExtras(b);
```

Then get it in your next activity:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String s = b.getString("key");
```

You also do need to switch your declarations of your TextViews and when you set them. You can't set them if they are not yet declared.

Edit: One more thing. I'm assuming you ***only*** want integers typed into that EditText. You should set the inputType on it, if you haven't already.

Edit 2: Don't feel retarded, we were all beginners at one point! Firstly, try using a bundle and see if what you type into your EditText is properly passed to the next activity.

Second, you set the `inputType` for the `EditText` in your XML file. Should be something like `android:inputType="number"`.

The declarations are these lines:

```
column1tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.column1text);
```

You're creating an object for your TextViews. Then, you set them here:

```
column1tv.setText(counter1);
```

You must create and instantiate the object before you can do anything with it.

Edit 3:
Okay, from the screenshot you posted, I gathered the following:

**First-** You're creating the objects `counter1, counter2, etc..` but you're never instantiating them with anything. Which is probably where you're getting your latest exception.

**Second-** You're getting the warning on the `String s = b.getString("lol");` because it's an unused local variable. (Check the problems tab in Eclipse and you'll see what the warnings/problems you have in your code). You're not doing anything with the string value that was passed from the previous activity.

Comment: I've updated my question with the current code - how do i set the inputType, and what are those declarations you speak of? Gosh i feel retarded...

Comment: Ah, so about the declarations, it's just the same as Captain Giraffe said?

It doesn't seem like the string is passed properly to the next activity, this is the error message i get: 02-23 22:13:17.424: E/AndroidRuntime(277): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{inno.games/inno.games.BillardScoreboardActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0

Comment: Do you know what line it is breaking at now? Did you set IDs for your TextViews in your XML file?

Comment: Nope, i'm having a very difficult time understanding those error messages in the LogCat properly, it doesn't seem to show on which line the error occurs. Yes, i set IDS for the textviews in my XML, those are the IDs i'm referring them by in the java.

Comment: Where are you creating counter1, counter2, etc..? Please post the code for that in your question.

Comment: Well, the counters are defined as integers in the .java, i don't see how i can create integers in the .xml - i updated the receiver .java now.

Comment: From the exception, it seems like you're trying to access a string value in your strings.xml file that isn't there.

Comment: Well, it might be the "String s = b.getString("lol")" - since it has lightbulb with a triangled ! beisde the code. It asks me to either remove s and all assignments, or keep s and all other side-assignments. You might have to check the codes that you sent to me in my code through (in order to be able to help me properly), since i'm quite sure i didn't implement them correctly.

Comment: By instantiating them you mean what? I checked my Problems tab through, all except 2 warnings are in the .xml tabs because i didn't put an Android namespace prefix, or didn't use strings instead of actually letters. Those 2 problems you see on the screenshot, are the only problems in the .java files

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the order of the column1tv.setText(...) and the column1tv = (TextView) findViewById(...).

```
// Assign new View to columnt1tv
column1tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.column1text); 

// change its appearance
column1tv.setText(counter1);
```

Also you want to setup an array of R.id's so you can loop through these repetitive constructs.

```
for( ... )
   columnTv[i] = (TextView) findByView( R_columnText[i] );
```

**Simplification with arrays short sample.**

```
class TheActivity extends Activity
{
    // Resource group id's
    private int R_columnTextIds[]={ R.id.column1text, R.id.column2text, 
               R.id.column3text, R.id.column4text};
    TextView columnTv[]= new TextView[4];
    // Now you can use loops.
    onCreate.... {
       .. get stuff and counter1
       for(int i = 0; i< columnTv.length; i++){
          columnTv[i] = (TextView) findByView( R_columnTextIds[i] );
          columnTv[i].setText( counter1 );
       }
```

Comment: I don't really get the array thing :/

Comment: Thanks, makes a bit more sense now. However, it doesn't accept "TextViews" in the 6th line of your code, is it a typo and was supposed to be TextView? Or do i have to create a class for it?

Answer (score 0):

Your string is definitely being conveyed within the `Intent` properly, because otherwise `i.getStringExtra("lol")` would return `null` if that name-value pair didn't exist. (It would be a very good idea for you to check whether the result you get is `null`, by the way, before attempting to parse an integer from the string). However, what seems to be the problem is that the string you're passing is actually a zero-length string, i.e. "", which means that `parseInt()` falls over when attempting to parse an integer out of it.

It seems that what you need to do is make `s` non-`final`, and add this into your button listener just before the `Intent` is fired:

```
s = startscore.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Hmm... Eclipse just keeps asking me to change the s to final, unless i do that, an error occurs. And when i write what you just wrote, it asks if i want to make s a local variable, do i want to do that?

Comment: Ah. Here's a good question to read through regarding that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class

Comment: Use the debugger to see what the string is actually being set to prior to being put into the `Intent`.

Comment: i'm not perfectly sure of how to do this.
When i use the debugger, a list of suspended RuntimeExceptions appears. And in that list there is something called: ActivityThread.main(String[]) line:4627 and Zygoteinit.main(String[]) line 626. When i click on each of them to see their variables, there appears 2 identical names, thread & args. with some strange values.

Answer (score 0):

You get the `startscore.getText().toString()` when it's probably empty (just after getting the EditText). So, the String you send is "". Try to get it just before

```
myIntent.putExtra("lol", s);
```

After, in receiving activity, you can test such as:

```
if(var != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(var)) {
    // deal with var
}
```

Then, you must try/catch operation on [Integer.parseInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) because it can throw a [NumberFormatException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) if the String is not a number (it's your case because var is "").